# Framework for .net Reflection.Emit simplification?

Tags: c#, .net, types, frameworks

Is there a framework, that makes the use of of Reflection.Emit easier? Something I can tell: Give me a class with a string field and get,set accessors.

The code I find in 
[Create a class type in code in .net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378033/create-a-class-type-in-code-in-net-c/3378155#3378155)
is what I need, but it is somewhat cryptic. I think a library with a simplified interface would boost productivity.

Comment: Try ExpandoObject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just described [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx). Unfortunately, it doesn't really (IMO) make it *easier* - it just makes it... different.

Personally, I'd just use `TypeBuilder`, `ILGenerator` and encapsulate the common functionality I need, i.e.

```
PropertyBuilder CreateProperty(TypeBuilder type, string name, Type propertyType)
{...}
```

Meta-programming is rarely simple, but from that detail you get a *very* good understanding of what is actually happening.

Comment: I'll certainly have a look at CodeDOM. From the first impression, it is appealing to me.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [CCI](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/).

Comment: CCI is certainly an option, that I will consider. Thanks.